# Nginx Config for HTTPS (WWW to non-WWW and all HTTP to HTTPS)

Tags: nginx, https, configuration, config

I am unable to get my HTTP --> HTTPS rules working correctly in my NGINX config. In addition to HTTPS, I'm also trying to redirect WWW to NON-WWW. However, I can't get WWW to even work.

Here is where I'm at:

http://example.com --> https://example.com (WORKS)

http://example.com?id=3 --> https://example.com?id=3 (WORKS WITH QUERY STRING)

http://www.example.com -> https://example.com (DOESNT WORK)

https://www.example.com (DOESN'T WORK)

URL's with WWW show "Server not found. Firefox can't find the server at www.example.com."

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    # this doesn't work. trying to http://www.example.com --> https://example.com
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

    # this works. http://example.com -> https://example.com
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/sslmate/www.example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslmate/www.example.com.key;

    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

    # this has www in server_name, and doesn't work
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/sslmate/www.example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslmate/www.example.com.key;

    server_name example.com;

    root /home/garrett/domains/example.com/public_html;
    access_log /home/garrett/domains/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/garrett/domains/example.com/logs/error.log;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    error_page 404 /404.php;
    error_page 403 /404.php;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-garrett.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # this block works, because I can access https://example.com correctly
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you didn't configure the www in the DNS...

Comment: You might be right, I have never installed an https certificate before. I followed directions best I could and here's what I did. My CNAME was a bunch of gobbledygook.www.mydomain.com and, of course, the value. Here is a pic: https://i.imgur.com/mgwp2DY.png

Comment: Do I just add a new line with www and that same value? Or do I remove all the characters that precede the www (makes more sense if you look at my pic). The ssl instructions from where I bought my certificate were not very clear